# Check if folder exist within current directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this command:

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p drive=Type your drive letter: 

%drive%:
if exist "Test Folder"
(
cd "Test Folder"
md "Test"
)
else
(
echo "Folder does not exist"
)

pause
```

It's not working, it says the command is invalid.

I want to change the drive letter and then verify if the folder exists, this also wont work

```
if exist %drive%\"Test Folder" (xxx)
```

How do i do it? Or is there any alternative using a vbs file? I think it would look prettier.

Comment: Please edit the script to use `rem @ECHO OFF` and observe the ouput from running it. It should lead to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closer, but there are still many issues to resolve. Please indent code appropriately.

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p drive=Type your drive letter:

%drive%:
if exist "Test Folder" (
    cd "Test Folder"
    mkdir "Test"
) else (
    echo "Folder does not exist"
)

pause
```